# Compile python code from text file in python program shows syntax error due to \n character

Tags: python, compilation, file-read

I have a text file containing python code. I need to read the text and check for errors using compile(). I cannot directly compile the file as I need to remove few text before compiling. When I compile the string by reading from file, it always shows syntax error due to \n character. How do I fix this?

```
------file.txt---------------
print('hello')
print('world')
-----------------------------    

------test.py----------------
f = open("/filepath/file.txt", "r")
codecontent = f.read()
f.close()

compile(codecontent, '', 'eval')

###output####
Syntaxerror at line 1 -> "print('hello')\n"
```

Comment: The doc for `compile` says: The mode argument specifies what kind of code must be compiled; it can be 'exec' if source consists of a sequence of statements, 'eval' if it consists of a single expression.

Comment: Thanks @ThierryLathuille that worked. Changing 'eval' to 'exec' compiled it successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
with open('filepath/file.txt') as f:
for line in f:
   x = compile(line, 'test', 'eval')
   exec(x)
   if 'str' in line:
      break
```

Answer (score 0):

Also this code using list comprehension

```
with open('filepath\file.txt') as f:
    [exec(compile(line,'test', 'eval')) for line in f]
```